# ng-click with oneway binding parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a variable without binding it, using a oneway binding on an ng-click. this doesn't work:

```
<button ng-click="setLabel('{{::param1}}', '{{::param2}}'">
```

it just passes a string '{{::paramX}}' instead of passing the value.
I don't want to pass param1, and param2 directly since it will be binded.

how can I solve it?

Comment: Try without the quotes surrounding your argument.  Like `<button ng-click="setLabel({{::param1}}, {{::param2}}">`

Comment: @ryanyuyu, already tried that i'm getting an exception: "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 15 of the expression"

Comment: how about passing `param1` and `param2` directly and doing `angular.copy ` inside of `setLable` function.

Comment: @Lekhnath the whole point is to skip the binding. that way it's still binding the parameters plus doing deep copy of the object.

Comment: Quick idea for a work around.  Store the original values in separate variables (that are set only once) and then just use those instead.

Comment: @Dano, I'm also facing same problem, did you found any solution ?

Comment: Refer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850494/one-way-data-binding-inside-ng-click/50850531#50850531](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850494/one-way-data-binding-inside-ng-click/50850531#50850531)