# One way data binding inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-click

I have two $scope array inside my controller.

```
$scope.arrayA= [false, false, false, false, false, false];
$scope.arrayB= [false, false, false, false, false, false];
```

arrayA will change depends on checkbox click. I have done this part.

arrayB will change values to be equal to arrayA only **when a button is clicked**.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="arrayB = arrayA" class="btn btn-search">Get Data</button>
```

The problem is once the button is clicked, two way data binding is implemented. arrayB will change everytime arrayA changes.

I only want arrayB to change when the button is clicked. Is there a way to use the angular one-way data binding `@` inside ng-click? You know like how we pass variables values in python as `varB = varA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning `arrayA` directly to `arrayB`, you need to create a copy of it, so that both variables don't refer to the same object.

```
arrayA = arrayB
```

The above assignment simply makes `arrayA` and `arrayB` to refer to the same object. On click of the button, you may try this:

```
arrayB = arrayA.map(item => item);
```

This will ensure that a new copy of the array is created, and since the values `varA` contains are primitive (boolean), there will be no conflicts.